# confudes with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

[image]

I have tried to understand the question but I got really confused.

So starting from node 3, the distance to other nodes are

3 to 1 = 3

3 to 2 = 1

3 to 4 = 4

3 to 5 = 2

3 to 6 = 3

3 to 7 = 2

and the question asks what is the third node added to the set S.

What I think it should be is 2->5->7->1->6->4 therefore the answer should be (B.7)

but the actual answer is (A.5)

Where did I made a mistake with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the algorithm works:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  \hline
  3 & \infty & 1 & 0 & \infty & \infty & 9 & 2\\
  \hline
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & \infty & 2 & 6 & 2
 \end{array}
$$

So at the next step algorithm will choose $5$ because it's current distance is minimal ($5 < 7$ breaks the tie) and it's not in $S$.

Comment: $$
\begin{array}{c|c}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  \hline
  3 & \infty & 1 & 0 & \infty & \infty & 9 & 2\\
  \hline
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & \infty & 2 & 6 & 2\\
  \hline
  5 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 2\\
  \hline
  7 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
  \hline
  1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
  \hline
  6 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
  \hline
  4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 2\\
 \end{array}
$$

Is this right? I tried to complete the table but not sure if I am right.

Comment: @AndyMin Just perfect!

Comment: @AndyMin no problem :)